# How to write code for some part of the android application in html and javascript and rest in java?

Tags: android, leaflet

I m working on a project related to maps. I want to use leaflet API in it so I want to know how can I make an android app with some portion of code using web technologies and other using java.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), and use it to display a webpage with your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Create the app as you normally would, using Java, and use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to run the web technologies part of it.